# Data array not beeing passed to Mail View

Tags: laravel

I'm Trying to pass a multidimensional array with data of multiple users to my view, so that I can send it as a list on an email. But I always get the error "undefined variable" when I call my array in my mail view.

I have already tried to call my array with foreach and for, neither did work, also tried to call the keys in my array directly on my view, but I also got "undefined variable".

**Function:**

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $tubes = DB::table('tubes')->where('status','received')->select('TubeID', 'TestArrivalDate')->get();
        $tubes = json_decode($tubes, true);
        if(!is_null($tubes)){
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          foreach ($tubes as $tube) {
            $diff = Carbon\Carbon::parse($tube['TestArrivalDate'])->diffInDays();
            $Email = DB::table('tubes')->join('profile', 'profile.ProfileID', 'tubes.ProfileID')->where('TubeID', $tube['TubeID'])->select('ProfileEmail', 'ProfileName')->get();
            $Email = array_flatten(json_decode($Email, true));
            if ($diff > 14) {
              $TubesDelay[]=array('TubeID' => $tube['TubeID'],'TestArrivalDate' => $tube['TestArrivalDate'], 'DaysWaiting' => $diff, 'ProfileEmail' => $Email[0], 'ProfileName' => $Email[1]);
            }
          }
          // dd($TubesDelay);
          Mail::send('mail.DelayedSamplesMail', $TubesDelay, function($message)
          {
              $message->from('kundenservice@test', 'kundenservice@test');
              $message->to(['m.lara@test'])->subject('Sample Delay');
          });
        }
   }
```

**View:**

```
  <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Poppins Light">
    <br />
    Following Samples are received and have delay:
    @foreach ($TubesDelay as $sample)
      <td>{{$sample}}</td>
    @endforeach
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </span>
```

What I want is to put the data of all the users in the array in the email as a list. So my array looks like this

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "TubeID" => 1005029
    "TestArrivalDate" => "2019-06-21"
    "DaysWaiting" => 61
    "ProfileEmail" => "mat@test.world"
    "ProfileName" => "MLB"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "TubeID" => 1005034
    "TestArrivalDate" => "2019-07-08"
    "DaysWaiting" => 44
    "ProfileEmail" => "mat@test.com"
    "ProfileName" => "MLB2"
  ]
```

I would like to have all the data in the array listed

```
TubeID 1005029
TestArrivalDate 2019-06-21
DaysWaiting 61
ProfileEmail mat@test.world
ProfileName MLB

TubeID 1005034
TestArrivalDate2019-07-08
DaysWaiting 44
ProfileEmail mat@test.com
ProfileName MLB2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the key for the array you sent to the view.

```
Mail::send('mail.DelayedSamplesMail', ['TubesDelay' => $TubesDelay], function($message) {...
```

The key will later be used as variables. Therefore, you may loop the `$TubesDelay` in the view.

**EDIT**
Change your loop to display all of the loop

```
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Poppins Light">
    <br />
    Following Samples are received and have delay:
    @foreach ($TubesDelay as $item)
        <td>{{ $sample['TubeID'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sample['TestArrivalDate'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sample['DaysWaiting'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sample['ProfileEmail'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sample['ProfileName'] }}</td>
    @endforeach
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</span>
```

Comment: But then how can I loop it on a for or foreach, wouldn't I get than the error "expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: With foreach yes, and I tried to loop my array also with a for and the email was empty

Comment: @matilarab Try ```dd($TubesDelay)``` on the view. Check what did you get before you decide to loop.

Comment: dd on the view right before my loop, shows me the array with the right values, but its empty after after foreach or     for ($i=0; $i > 0; $i++)
      <td>{{$TubesDelay[$i]}}</td>
    endfor

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to dd($TubesDelay) then try using the below code:

```
Mail::send('mail.DelayedSamplesMail', $TubesDelay, function($message) use($TubesDelay)
{
  $message->from('kundenservice@test', 'kundenservice@test');
  $message->to(['m.lara@test'])->subject('Sample Delay');
});
```

Comment: "Undefined variable: TubesDelay" when I try to foreach or dd($TubesDelay)

Comment: Define your array outside the foreach loop. Inside the foreach loop insert data to array

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new and don't understand what you mean